# Filter out items from cursor

Tags: android, android-cursor

I'm trying to remove an item from a cursor object, and I'm not sure how to do it (or if it's possible). I don't actually want to remove the item from the database, just 'filter' it and not display it, depending on user settings.

For example here, `FILTER_TEXT` is from the application preferences and it contains text that the cursor must contain or else it is removed.

```
Cursor mCursor = mDB.query(dbTable, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,
            KEY_URL}, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            if (!mCursor.getString(1).contains(FILTER_TEXT)) {
                // Remove cursor item here
            }
        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

I was fairly sure this was the right way to tackle this, but I can't find any way to remove an item from a cursor...

Any help would be appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want to filter it before it even gets in to the `Cursor`. Try altering the query that generates it so that those items never even get in to it. This way, SQLite can filter out those unneeded things before they use up any more resources.

You can do this by sending things to the `selection' parameter of 'query', something like:

```
KEY_NAME + " LIKE '%" + FILTER_TEXT + "%'"
```

*(That may need some tweaking, my SQL is rusty.)*

You may also want to look in to [`SQLQueryBuilder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html).

As to if it's possible, I couldn't find anything in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) that would do what you wanted. I think `Cursor` is read-only.

Comment: For more info on LIKE and it's syntax, check out http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like

Comment: Awesome, that seems like it will do the job. Do you know if there is an "OR" sql operator in this case? I have multiple `FILTER_TEXT` parameters.

Comment: I think you should be able to chain them together by dropping them in parentheses with an OR between them.

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to implement a i.e. a List that is filterable by the user you can use a CursorAdapter and just set the ListViews [setTextFilterEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setTextFilterEnabled%28boolean%29) to true
- You can use a [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html), to load a new cursor in the background and swap it in when its loaded.