# SimpleCursorAdapter remove values

Tags: java, android, listview, cursor

I have a `ListView` on each row i have a `LinearLayout` with some objects in it (mostly some TextViews).

This ListView i fill it dynamically from a cursor. In this cursor i have one value true or false.

I want to hide or make non clickable the lines with value false. I try this code but doesn't work

```
public void contentProviderInitialized(final Cursor cursor) {

    SimpleCursorAdapter commonTickets = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MyClass.this,
        R.layout.row_ticketing, cursor, new String[] {"price", "productName", "stopName" },
        new int[] { R.id.ticketing_price, R.id.ticketing_product, R.id.ticketing_stop_name }
    ) {
        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            String enabledStr = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("enabled"));
            String product = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("productName"));
            boolean enabled = Boolean.parseBoolean(enabledStr);
            LinearLayout ticketingRow = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ticketing_row);
            if (enabled) {
                ticketingRow.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                ticketingRow.setEnabled(false);
            }
            super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
        };
        MyClass.this.ticketing_list_view.setAdapter(commonTickets);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the full exception and your StackTrace.

Comment: I didn't say something about an exception. The problem is that the rows with false values are still clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override isEnabled on the adapter

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#isEnabled(int)

This answer seems to hint at it.  Use movetoposition on the cursor.  It sounds like the performance would be bad with that, though, so you might want to do some caching of true/false values based on numeric position?  Try it out.  See how it goes.  The caching might be a waste.

Answer (score 0):

This was a great help to try another aproach:

[Android - how to delete item from a cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724714/android-how-to-delete-item-from-a-cursor/18154738#18154738)

Add the positions you want to see to a new MatrixCursor and swap your Cursor to the new Matrix Cursor