# removing cursor based items in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

This is how my recyclerView is coded (partially):

```
expensesListCursor = dbc.listExpenses(selectedDate);
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            rvExpenses.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            rvExpenses.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

            mAdapter = new AdapterExpensesList(expensesListCursor,getActivity());
            rvExpenses.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

here's how my dbc.ListExpenses is written

```
public Cursor listExpenses(String date){
        Cursor cursor;
        cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_EXPENSES, new String[] {"rowid as _id", "description, cost"}, "date='" + date + "'", null, null, null, "_id asc");

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor;
    }
```

and here's how AdapterExpensesList is written

```
public class AdapterExpensesList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterExpensesList.ViewHolder> {

 Cursor myDataCursor;

public AdapterExpensesList(Cursor expensesListCursor, Context context){
            myDataCursor = expensesListCursor;

    }
```

As you can probably see above, the items in my RecyclerView is taken directly from cursor. My problem is now, I'd like to implement the feature to remove some of the data in the RecyclerView. From the examples I found on the net, usually here's how they did it:

```
private ArrayList<String> mDataset;
public void remove(String item) {
    int position = mDataset.indexOf(item);
    mDataset.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
  }
```

The problem is my data is a cursor object, and cursor doesn't have the .remove(position) like ArrayList for example. So how do I achieve the same thing, that is to remove certain data from certain position?

Note: I just want to remove data from particular (selected) position, and not the data inside the database itself.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I am also facing same problem .

Answer (score 0):

You can not delete items from the cursor check it here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6724929/5492047

Instead you can convert your cursor items in list https://www.javatpoint.com/java-list or arraylist  https://www.javatpoint.com/java-arraylist

and achieve your task.